# Conjecture about difference of Fibonacci numbers and primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, conjectures

I'm curious to see if this conjecture is true: if $ m > 4 $ is a positive integer not divisible by $ 2 $ or $ 3 $, it's possible to find a positive integer $ n $ such that the difference of the $ 2 $ Fibonacci numbers $ F_{m+n}-F_n $ is a prime number.

Various example of $ [m, n] $, with the smallest n, are $[5,3],[7,3], [11,4], [13,5], [17,3],..., [619,1353]...$

I don't know if this could be of any help: I converted the primes I found that way in the Zeckendorf representation and they are an alternating sequence of $ 1 $ and $ 0 $ ending with two adjacent $ 0 $ and $ 1 $ (and eventually just various $ 0 $)

Edit: I posted this problem on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440149/conjecture-about-difference-of-fibonacci-numbers-and-primes) too

Comment: You wouldn't order a pizza from two different stores at the same time; you shouldn't post a question to two different websites at the same time. The custom here is to post to one site, wait several days; then, if you haven't had a satisfactory resolution, post to the other site. But what is most important when you post to two sites is that you link the posts to each other. This, other users have done for you; you should have done it yourself.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142654/discussion-on-question-by-user967210-conjecture-about-difference-of-fibonacci-nu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I have posted the solutions including the hard cases upto $n=3\ 000$ in the chat. I am now working on the hard cases in the range $n=3\ 000-4\ 000$

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your great work! I want to repost on Mathoverflow the conjecture adding samples of your findings

Answer (score -2):

I can't say for sure, but intuitively, since primes are truly random and infinitely many exist, then it's very likely the conjecture is true: that it's always possible.

I was able to come up with this semi-proof: $F(x)$ is the x-th number in the Fibonacci sequence

In the interval that lies between $F(A+x)-2(F(x))$ up to $F(A+x)$, there exists just around ${2F(x)\over \ln(F(A+x))}$ primes. And, we know that F(A+x)--F(x) is in this interval.

Since the interval holds 2(F(x)) integer numbers, then the chance of randomly selecting a Prime, if you choose a number in that interval, is $1\over ln(F(A+x))$. We will always choose the number F(A+x)-F(x).

The chance of failure, is, 1 - $1\over ln(F(A+x))$ for the first attempt. If every time F(A+x)-F(x) failed to hit a prime number, you tried again, but increased x by 1, forever, then the chance of hitting at least one prime number is 1 -- every attempt has failed, or $1 - \prod_{x=0}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{ln(F(A+x))}\right).$

Regardless of what A is, the chance eventually converges to 100%.

Here that is in desmos. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/29bkcvb5mt

In all seriousness though, this assumes that selecting F(A+x)--F(x) every time as our lottery numbers, is as arbitrary as selecting any other number or function of x. If we waited for truly random selection to land upon F(A+x)-F(x), it'd take increasingly forever, as A is larger, and then on top of that we'd have just a $1/\ln(F(A+x))$ chance that it's prime.

I suppose though, that since we could do THAT forever too, we can randomly land upon a F(A+x)--F(x) infinitely many times. And so eventually one of the F(A+x)--F(x) would be landed upon randomly and on top of that also be prime. (regardless of A)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: @NoxaraSalva A cannot be 100 because cannot be even, read carefully the beginning of my post

Comment: Yeah, whoops. I suppose that's why they deleted it.